# Single result not showing when joining table

Tags: sql

I have modified a SQL query in WordPress through a filter for the geomywp plugin so that I can search users by taxonomy and distance.

The end query looks like this

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS u.ID as id   FROM  wp_users u 
INNER JOIN wppl_friends_locator gmwlocations ON u.ID = gmwlocations.member_id 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON u.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '47'
```

The `term_taxonomy_id` changes depending on what category they are searching for.

The really weird thing about this is that it only works if there is more than 1 result.  If there is just 1 result then this query shows 0 results.

If I remove the join to the geolocation table like so:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS u.ID as id   FROM  wp_users u 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON u.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '47'
```

Then it works for taxonomies that only have a single user.

I can't figure out why joining this table stops the query working for single results.  I have never come across this before.  I ran the query outside of wordpress direct in mysql and same behaviour occurs.

I need to leave this join for when plugin searches by distance.  Can anyone shed light on this odd behaviour?

Comment: How are you even verifying that there is one result if the result set comes back empty?

Comment: I can see in the wp_term_relationships table that there is an entry with term_taxonomy_id that matches.  If I delete the inner join to wppl_friends_locator table then the single result comes back.  Am I misunderstanding how joins work?

Comment: Yes, I think you are.  That record is being filtered off earlier by the joins most likely.  If you look at the data from all the tables, I believe you will see this.

Comment: Yes, I see now that the records don't exist in the wppl_friends_locator table.  So when I join tables it gets rid of any records that don't exist in all joined tables?  How do I make like an optional join so it would have the columns but they would just be blank if its not in that table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try joining the tables together using a `LEFT JOIN`, which would prevent records on the left side of the join from being filtered off in the event that no match occurs:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS u.ID as id
FROM wp_users u 
LEFT JOIN wppl_friends_locator gmwlocations
    ON u.ID = gmwlocations.member_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
    ON u.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '47'
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works when I run it direct in SQL but plugin still doesnt return results so i guess there is another issue also